# javascript onbeforeunload not showing custom message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have custom message to onbeforeunload event and was working well but I noticed today that it's not showing my message anymore. Instead it shows "changes you made may not be saved"

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {

    return 'Custom message'
}
```

can anyone please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/276660)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To avoid scamming, chromium and hence chrome have decided to remove the ability to set a custom message in the `onbeforeunload` dialog.

See this [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587940) from the 18th of February, 2016.

> onbeforeunload dialogs are used for two things on the Modern Web:
>    1.  Preventing users from inadvertently losing data.
>    2.  Scamming users.
>
> In an attempt to restrict their use for the latter while not stopping the former, we are going to not display the string provided by the webpage. Instead, we are going to use a generic string.
>
> Firefox already does this[...]

Comment: Is there a workaround to show a custom message to the user?\

Comment: @R.S.K no, that would defeat the reason why they did it.

Comment: I'm so glad they finally did this. One less trick for leech parasites on the web.

Comment: yeah but unfortunately those who abused it once again screw those who didn't abuse it... it'd be nicer if it said: "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave the current page" or something to that tune.

Comment: I agree.. the scammers have crapped on us.. I want to warn my user when they leave close my site, if it's offline.

Comment: @baash05 you can catch user's mouse scrolling over top of the page and show the warning - https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce