# Disable "Changes you made may not be saved" pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following frontend code to export a `.csv` document.

**HTML**

```
  <form id="tool-export" method="post" action="export/">{% csrf_token %}
    <a id="export-link" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">DOWNLOAD</a>
  </form>
```

**JS**

```
  $('#export-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    var form = link.closest('form');

    var project_id = proj_id.find(":selected").val();
    var input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'project_id').val(project_id);
    form.append($(input));

    var project_type = proj_type.val();
    input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'project_type').val(project_type);
    form.append($(input));

    form.submit();
  });
```

Export works well and I get the correct document. But also I receive the ***Changes you made may not be saved*** message after clicking on the export link. How to disable this message? I don't want to see it.

[image]

Comment: change your `<a>` tag to a button or input tag without the href

Comment: which framework/plugins you use? The alert you see is created using the `beforeunload` event. To disable it you should unbind that event...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why this alert appears but maybe if you `return false` after call `form.submit()` it will be works well.

Comment: @Dekel, you are right. Post your answer and I will sign it as the solution.

Comment: @trex, glad I could help you with this one. Sorry I missed your comment. You are welcome to find some of my other answers and vote a few of them if you like to :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

@Dekel helped me to get it.

The message is the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event. 
And I can disable it with `window.onbeforeunload = null;`.

**JS**

```
  $('#export-link').click(function(e) {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    var form = link.closest('form');

    var project_id = proj_id.find(":selected").val();
    var input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'project_id').val(project_id);
    form.append($(input));

    var project_type = proj_type.val();
    input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'project_type').val(project_type);
    form.append($(input));

    form.submit();
  });
```

Comment: **window.onbeforeunload = null;** working in chrome and IE but in Firefox still getting the popup.

Comment: How to implement this in drupal?

Comment: According to MDN specs for `beforeunload`:
_The HTML specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML specification for more details._

@NNR also from MDN:
_However note that not all browsers support this method, and some instead require the event handler to implement one of two legacy methods:_
read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Comment: @srgbnd If we have custom requirement on onbeforeunload and if we make it null, it works on button click. But what about if we want to call onbeforeunload logic on browser cross button, then how will that work?

Comment: Is there an addon for this, which will allow me to block it for all/specific websites?

Comment: this solution not working if document contains an iframe

Comment: not working for me, I'm trying it on `document.ready()`

Answer (score 11):

In jQuery simply use :

```
$(window).off('beforeunload');
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
     // Your Code here 
      return null;  // return null to avoid pop up
    }
```

Comment: Not possible in Chromium since ~2016 https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782307/1454622 .

Comment: Seems to be working in Chrome now (Sept 2023)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same error with embedding Google-Form in Chrome,

I can verify that none of the found solutions helped me. Here is the screenshot of my pop-up:

[image]

The only solution I've managed to implement was hiding the element and then unhiding/creating the new `iframe` with the current embed. Here's the part of my code:

```
       if (oldvalue !== value) { // checks the id of the form (value) is not the same
         // set value of the id
         $('#info').text(value); 
         // check the element exists
         let exists = value;
         if($("#" + value).length == 0) {
           //it doesn't exist
           exists = false;
         }
         // hide all child elements of the div for forms
         parent.children().hide();
         // create new node if needed
         if (!exists)
         {
           // create new form element and embed the form
           $("#google-form").clone().attr("id",value).attr('src', record.url).appendTo(parent);
         }
         // unhide error element
         $("#" + value).show();
       }
```

The full code of my solution is [here](https://github.com/Max-Makhrov/google-form-to-sheet.gs).

Comment: The above solutions stopped working probably because they just simply stopped developers from controlling the browser behaviour dur to safety concerns.