# How to disable "Changes you made may not be saved." dialog box (Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

A similar question has been answered ([Disable "Changes you made may not be saved" pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425682/disable-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-pop-up-window)), but somehow this still does not work for me.

I'm attempting to disable the `Changes you made may not be saved.` dialog box on form input changes. I know Chrome has removed the custom message capability, but I am having difficulty disabling the box altogether. I have the following javascript at the bottom of some HTML code:

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  };

  window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Neither of the two work for me. When I type `window.onbeforeunload` into the inspector console, I get a `null` return value. Can the `window.onbeforeunload = null;` be called anywhere within the lifespan of the page? Perhaps I'm misplacing it somewhere?

Comment: something could be adding an event listener the "right" way, i.e. `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', ...)` - but if it's your code, you'd know that already

Comment: if your page uses jQuery, you may be lucky and `$(window).off('beforeunload');` *may* work for you - as you've shared nothing about what libraries etc you use, this is a shot in the dark

Comment: @JaromandaX, that worked, thanks! Geez. I wonder why that happened? If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: before I add as an answer, it would be useful to know what JS libraries you are using (obviously jQuery is one), what others? It may be that some *helpful* jQuery plugin/addon is adding that *helpful*" event handler :p

Comment: You just have to use the opposite of whatever function you used to add the handler in the first place. If you use `.on()` you remove it with `.off`. If you used `.addEventListener` you use `.removeEventListener`. And if you used `window.onbeforeunload = function` you use `window.onbeforeunload = null`

Comment: @JaromandaX, there are many libraries being used - jQuery, Semantic, Elemental, react are just a few. Sorry if that's not helpful..

Comment: well, one of them is adding a `beforeunload` handler - I wont post as an answer, because it's not at all helpful without knowing what's doing it

Comment: Very late comment,  but I had the same situation - with the window.onbeforeunload = null  solution not working, and using jQuery .off() worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery then below code will work for you

```
$(window).off('beforeunload');
```