# Wicket: Disable “Changes you made may not be saved” pop-up window in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I click on submit button in my form in modal (I use apache wicket). But I receive the **Changes you made may not be saved** message after clicking on submit button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsJ5O.jpg)

How to disable this message? I don't want to see it. I found the same problem here:
[Disable "Changes you made may not be saved" pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425682/disable-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-pop-up-window)
but I don't know how to resolve this using apache wicket.

Comment: Lets show html & java. Impossible to guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `ModalWindow#showUnloadConfirmation(false)`.

https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/72a5d312a1dfe63349a8ab963d9126cab5525a20/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.java#L641