# Reload a page without prompt message

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to reload page. But getting prompt message.

```
location.reload();

$window.location.reload();
```

Is there a way to reload page without prompting a message?

Comment: location.reload(); works without prompt message on chrome for me

Comment: I don't get a prompt message with location.reload() either. What does the message say?

Comment: can you tell us what the prompt message says?

Comment: what prompt you are getting.  If the current page opened by posting the form on previous page, its browser functionality to prompt the user before resubmitting the page again if you try to do so..

Comment: What browser are you using? Tried in chrome and ie and no prompt.

Comment: Getting this - **Changes you made may not be saved.**

Comment: Make sure your application does not have `window.onunload` event, this will prompt a message if you want to reload or leaving the page.

Comment: Or if you are using jQuery `$( window ).unload`

Answer (score 4):

try using `window.onbeforeunload = null;` before `window.location.reload()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **window.location = window.location.href**;

Comment: Tried but doesn't worked. Not refreshing/reloading page.

Comment: The message is the beforeunload event. And you can disable it with window.onbeforeunload = null; you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425682/disable-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-pop-up-window

Comment: Tried **window.onbeforeunload = null;**, working in Chrome and IE not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery simply use -

```
  $(selector).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).off('beforeunload');
    window.location.reload()
  });
```