# Actually prevent this page from creating dialogs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to prevent any additional dialogs without needing the additional dialog box to be checked. I'm implementing an autosave feature that is called right before the user closes or refreshes the page, so the "changes you made may not be saved" pop-up is unnecessary. I looked at [beforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425682/disable-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-pop-up-window) and had no luck.

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;

$(window).on('unload', function (e) {
    $page.model.save(true, function (success) {});
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows updated my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try, instead of just calling

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Instead use:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
 window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```