# How to change the message “Changes you made may not be saved.” for window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change messge “Changes you made may not be saved.” on leaving the page.I am using window.onbeforeunload for this.

Comment: in modern browsers, you can not - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782104/javascript-onbeforeunload-not-showing-custom-message (it applies to more than chrome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which browsers you are referring to, you cannot change this message.

I assume you are referring to Chrome in this instance, which removed support for changing the `beforeunload` message as far back as v51: [Chrome v51 Deprecations](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/chrome-51-deprecations?hl=en#remove-custom-messages-in-onbeforeload-dialogs)

The main reason it was removed was due to scammers using the message to trick people so Google made it always the same message to avoid confusion.

> With this change, Chrome will be consistent with Safari 9.1 and later, as well as Firefox 4 and later.

Comment: FYI - firefox shows the message `This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.`

Comment: If you have something new, please post an answer on the Chrome-specific canonical question that is linked in comments on the question instead of answering a duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you for replying simon.I am using google chrome browser.Is there any other way we can do this

Comment: Nope, otherwise scammers would still have a way of doing this.